# Group names in GAP character table library

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, gap, computer-algebra-systems

Let $G = M_{12}.2$, automorphism group of the Mathieu group $M_{12}$.

In GAP, with `DisplayAtlasInfo("M12.2");;` we get information about G as listed [here](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/%7EThomas.Breuer/ctbllib/ctbltoc/data/M12.2.html) or [here](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/%7EThomas.Breuer/atlasrep/htm/data/M12.2.htm).

One of the maximal subgroups is listed as having structure `D8.(S4x2)`.

So in ATLAS notation, I think this would mean that the subgroup has a normal subgroup $D_8$ with quotient $S_4 \times C_2$.

But as far as I can tell by computing with GAP, this maximal subgroup does not have a dihedral group $D_8$ as a normal subgroup. It does have $C_2^3$ as a normal subgroup, with quotient $S_4 \times C_2$. Also it seems in the ATLAS this maximal is denoted by $(2_{+}^{1+4}:S_3).2$, for example [here](http://atlas.math.rwth-aachen.de/Atlas/v3/spor/M12/).

Is this correct and what does `D8.(S4x2)` mean in GAP? More generally how to interpret the group names used in GAP?

Comment: This can be viewed [here](https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap39.html#X87BF1B887C91CA2E)

Comment: There is indeed no maximal subgroup of $M_{12}.2$ that has the dihedral group of order $8$ as a normal subgroup, so there must be a  mistake in the displayed information.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: @kabenyuk: Thanks. Although it seems (see answer by ahulpke) here the issue is not with `StructureDescription`, which for this maximal subgroup is something different to `D8.(S4x2)`. But rather that the identifier for this particular group used in the character table library is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a misprint in the library (that then propagated to web pages you refer to that just pull data from the library).

In the printed version of the ATLAS the group is an extension of one named $M_8.S_4$, here $M_8$ is a Mathieu-type name for $Q_8$. However the extra 2 does not preserve the $Q_8$, which makes the name $M_8.S_4.2$ misleading. Better use the name from the ATLAS webpages you cite.
An alternative name could be a non-split extension $2^3\cdot (2\times S_4)$.

This will be corrected in a future release.

Comment: Thanks for the response and for confirming this, I appreciate it.